# Mounting a Windows partition without giving execute permission

Tags: permissions, mount, ntfs

How can I mount a Windows partition so that the files within it don't have execution permission? I mount a Windows partition using:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 win
```

`win` is a folder in my home dir.

This of course works. But files in the mounted partition are given execute permission, or to be specific, `777`.

How to mount the partition so that files are given `666` or other permission?

Comment: [Mount NTFS Partition on Startup in Ubuntu](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23843/23862#23862)

Comment: @Gilles. Thanks Gilles. I found your post searching with `umask`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man mount` has a section "Mount options for ntfs" (assuming your file system is NTFS and not FAT) where it says,

> uid=value, gid=value and umask=value
>
> Set the file permission on the filesystem.  The umask value is given in octal.  By default, the files are owned by root and not readable  by  some‐body else.

`sudo mount /dev/sda3 win/ -o fmask=111`
will mount the ntfs file system with all files having
`rw-rw-rw-` permissions.

Directories will still be executable, but this is needed to allow you to cd into them.

Comment: Thanks for the `umask` options. But I think `fmask=111` should be used instead, cause `umask=111` would make the directories non-executable so that I could not `cd` into it. For me, `fmask=111` does the job.