# Automounting NTFS Hard drive in Centos 7

Tags: centos, automounting

I am using Centos 7. I have a question. I have a NTFS formatted drive which I want to automount when I login. Right now I need to always click on the HDD name on my computer windows and entering root pass. Is this possible?

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Same [process as in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23843/mount-ntfs-partition-on-startup-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect GNOME Disks will be too old to do this in CentOS, but it seems worth a look.  Run the "Disks" app (maybe under a "utilities" menu), select your disk, then the ntfs partition (under **Volumes**), then click the cogs button under the partition.  If there's an "Edit mount options", you can play with the GUI and do it that way.  I'd suggest not mounting it automatically during boot if you don't need to, for sake of [robustness](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/jZDxC2n0PYE) and simplicity (otherwise I think you'd need a uid=youruser option for permissions).

In either case you will need to create the mount point.  `mkdir /media/ntfs` or so, as root/using sudo.

Without GNOME Disks, you can add a line to `/etc/fstab` yourself.  *Caution*: a mistake could break your boot process.  You should identify the partition by UUID for robustness.  (Particularly if it's a removable disk, though I don't know why it asks you for a root password in that case).  Set the options `user,noauto` to let you mount it yourself after boot:

```
UUID=xx /media/ntfs ntfs user,noauto 0 0
```

You can use `lsblk -f` to list all hard drive partitions and their UUIDs.  (E.g. when you took the screenshot it was sdc1, so look for the matching line and copy the UUID column).

Comment: this is the settings that i make right now http://i62.tinypic.com/1zgfc50.jpg and this is the lsblk -f output http://i58.tinypic.com/23sg8ro.jpg . I didnt restarted pc because i am afraid of not to boot the system. Do you think this is okay now?

Comment: And this is my current fstab file http://i62.tinypic.com/2uti5ol.jpg

Comment: ah, `nofail` should avoid any problems booting.  The changes will take effect immediately.  (but it can be a good idea to reboot to check that actually works).  However as I said if you boot with it plugged in, I bet it gets mounted so only root can read or write the files.  Solution: either uncheck the "at startup" tickbox, or add option `uid=myusername`.  Unchecking seems simplest to me.

Comment: should i use my root user or normal user in uid= ?

Comment: with these settings "nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,user,noauto" it stills ask me to enter password when i try to click on hdd on my computer.

Comment: If the Mount Options dialog is lying (about the additional auth bit) then I have no idea, sorry.